# Remove splash screen from backstack in navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the navigation component in the app. I created a nav graph with fragments SplashScreen->fragmentA->fragmentB. I am using NavDeepLinkBuilder to generate a pending intent for a push notification to open the app at the fragmentB like this:

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation_graph)
        .setDestination(R.id.fragmentB)
        .setArguments(args.toBundle())
        .createPendingIntent()
```

After clicking on the notification fragmentB will open but after clicking on the back button the splash screen will open and the application opens again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot this type of work in kotlin but I achieve this job in java.here is a code:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the FragmentB action of navigation_graph you can use

```
  <fragment android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        ...
        >

        <action 
            ...
            app:popUpTo="@id/splash"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

This pops up the fragments in the backstack until SplashFragment has reached including SplashFragment. This will work only if Splash screen is a activity. If it is a launcher activity, start MainActivity as Navigation host, destroy SplashActivity.